# List all NAS server present in LAN using C#

Tags: c#

I want to List all NAS server present in LAN using C#.
Any idea or code snippet is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How will you determine wheter or not it's a NAS? Seems like a really vague description.

Comment: Ya I mean to say that only How will I determine wheter or not it's a NAS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's is any reliable way on how to determine if a device in your network is actually a NAS.

If your NAS servers follow some naming schema it might be possible to detect them through their names:

- [Retreiving a list of network computer names using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx)

Hope that helps.